# Get file duration uploaded from custom field wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to get the duration of audio file when uploaded through custom field and save it in the post meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has built in audio functions using the [ID3 library](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) that will help you achieve this.

First you will hook into ACF using the [acf/save_post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) hook. Then you will use the WP function [wp_read_audio_metadata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_audio_metadata) to get the meta data of the audio file. Lastly you will use the [update_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function to save the data to the post. Something like this:

```
function save_audio_duration($post_id) {
    // Get the WP Uploads Directory (where ACF saves files)
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploads_dir = ( $uploads['baseurl'] . $uploads['subdir'] );

    // Get the file name from ACF & create the file string
    $file_obj = get_field('audio_file', $post_id);
    $file = $uploads_dir . '/' . $file_obj['filename'];

    // Use the wp_read_audio_metadata() function to get data
    $metadata = wp_read_audio_metadata( $file );

    // Save the file length to the post meta
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'audio_length', $metadata['length']);
}

// Will execute AFTER post has been saved (change "20" to "1" to execute before)
add_action('acf/save_post', 'save_audio_duration', 20);
```

**Note:** `$metadata['length']` will return the time in seconds while `$metadata['length_formatted']` will return the time in a formatted string.

**Note x2:** If you change the "20" to "1" in the action to execute this BEFORE the fields are saved to the post you will need to change the `get_field()` function to `$_POST['audio_file']` as the function will be executed before ACF saves the fields to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I change a little your good code for vídeos:

```
function save_video_duration($post_id) {

    // Get the file name from ACF & create the file string
    $file_obj = get_field('video_file', $post_id);

    // Get the WP Uploads Directory (where ACF saves files)
    $file = get_attached_file( attachment_url_to_postid( get_field('video_file', $post_id) ) );

    // Use the wp_read_audio_metadata() function to get data
    $metadata = wp_read_video_metadata($file);

    // Save the file length to the post meta
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'video_file_length', $metadata['length']);
}

// Will execute AFTER post has been saved (change "20" to "1" to execute before)
add_action('acf/save_post', 'save_video_duration', 20);
```

Thanks